# 100% width horizontal jQuery accordion

Tags: jquery, fullscreen, accordion

I've made this accordion which works fine in webkit browsers only.
I can't figure out what's causing it to break in non-webkit browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/gurtfrobe/SMjxK/1/

Excuse the crude code, I'm not too hot on Javascript.

All input greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which browsers it breaks on? Tested FF & Chrome and working.

Comment: Also you should't use console.log, because IE6 doesn't support it and then javascript fails.

Comment: It breaks on FF, IE7,8,9 (not supporting 6), haven't tested Opera. Thanks for the console.log tip, I'll remove that and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

So I've figured part of it out. It now works on Firefox, Opera and IE9 as well.

Only Webkit browsers can retrieve an element's position as a percentage. Firefox et al will convert the value to pixels. Therefore assuming the LEFT value is set as a percentage:

```
var myvar = $('#myitem').css('left');
```

Will save the percentage value in Chrome and Safari BUT other browsers will convert that percentage to a pixel value.

To get round this you have to firstly assign the LEFT value as an inline style and then change how the jQuery obtains the value. It now becomes:

```
var myitem = $('#myitem');
var myitemleft = myitem[0].style.left;
```

Note, there's probably a shorthand version of that code but my knowledge isn't that great.

If anyone knows what might cause it to not work in IE7&8 I'd appreciate the help. If I solve it I'll share my findings here.

Answer (score 0):

Made with a friend by your script under last IE, FF & Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/quadrian/z94baosx/

Comment: Please provide the relevant code in the answer. Link only answers are discouraged.